# Background colors not changing till page revisited only in android 11

Tags: text, colors, background, circular-dependency

The colors to one-page turn charcoal, which I don't have set anywhere only on android 11 phone. Then when I revisit it turns to colors in code. Another page switches colors sometimes, and the tint is a little darker. I tried moving around the color code to no avail. In android 10 it works fine though

Here the background color, text color, and circular background codes

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+_s));
t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#"+_s));
android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable gd = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#"+_c));
gd.setCornerRadius((int)_r);
v.setBackground(gd);
v.setElevation((int)_s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out i left force dark mode on in developer options and it turned some fields different colors.